# Can i send firebase update notification to the older app version on playstore which earlier did not have a firebase connection?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already have an app on google playstore which was not earlier connected with firebase. Now i want to update my app and send notification through firebase to the users. Can i do that?

Comment: do you realize what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK to your app, that includes code that generates a unique ID for each app instance that allows it to receive push notifications.

You can send push notification to users of your app that have a version after you installed Firebase. You cannot send notifications (through Firebase Cloud Messaging at least) to users that have a version of your app before you added Firebase to it.

Comment: ..Can you please tell me how can I send a notification for update to the old version users that was not connected to firebase.

Comment: You can't send messages through FCM to a version of the app that didn't include FCM.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do it if you update the app with firebase**

Comment: That would not be sending an "update notification to the older app version", would it?

Answer (score 0):

When a user launches your app which contains code for the Firebase SDK (FB), an ID and TOKEN is generated. This allows FB to be able to identify the instance of your application that is installed, and targets it for any particular use case.
Unless the user has opened your app with the newly added FB SDK code, then their instance cannot be registered with FB to receive and send any data to FB servers. After all, no code has been executed. All the user has done is just update the app. Simply updating the app doesn't execute any code. They will have to run/open the app and allow the line of code which instantiates the FB instance, to be called.
Because of this, you are unable to send notifications to older versions that never had the FB SDK. The users with the older version will have to update the app and run it, to receive notifications.